# Count the total number of characters in a word document (.docx) using Swing

Tags: java, swing, text

Actually I am new to the Swing platform, but somehow I managed to make the code to count the total number of lines in word document, but now I need to count the total number of characters in the word document.

Here is my code to count the number of lines in word document by using Swing, how can I alter this to count the words?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
      if(e.getSource()==openfile){    
          JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();    
          int i=fc.showOpenDialog(this);    
          if(i==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){    
              File f=fc.getSelectedFile();    
              String filepath=f.getPath();  
              JT_Filechooser.setText(filepath);
              JT_FileName.setText(f.getName());
              try{ 
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

              XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

              List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

              int count = 0;
              for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(para.getText());
              }
              System.out.println("No. of lines : "+count);
              JT_LinesCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
              fis.close();
              }catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();  }

          }    
      }    
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below count add a character count.

```
int charCount = 0;
```

Then inside of your loop.

```
charCount += para.getText().length();
```

After the loop your charCount should be the number of characters.

Comment: Thanks matt,let me try

Comment: ,i got my output. Thanks a lot